# Inner join table that have to be used two times for different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `users`:

```
id         name     
-----      -----    
1          Mark     
2          John    
3          Paul     
4          Dave    
5          Chris
```

and table `matches`:

```
id    sender    receiver   matched
--    ------    --------   -------
1        2         5          2
2        1         3          0
3        1         2          0
```

So John have sent 1 request for match and his match is accepted.
Also John have receive 1 match which is still not accepted.

I'm using this code to find the names of the users by their ids

```
SELECT matches.sender as sender,matches.receiver as receiver,users.name as `userName`,
 users.user as `userName2` FROM `matches`
  INNER JOIN `users` ON matches.sender = users.id
WHERE '$id' IN (sender,receiver) AND matched='2'
```

but it's pulling out only sender's userName . When I type

```
...ON matches.sender = users.id AND matches.receiver = users.id ....
```

the result is 0

So I need to pull out the names of the 2 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want two joins:

```
select m.*, us.name as sender_name, ur.name as receiver_name
from matches m join
     users us
     on m.sender = us.id join
     users ur
     on m.receiver = ur.id
where 2 in (m.sender, m.receiver) and
      m.matched = 2;
```